# Client-side cookies in Racket

Tags: cookies, racket

I'm trying to re-write some Common Lisp web-scraping code in Racket.

In Common Lisp, I'm POSTing a login request, and storing the cookie-jar for subsequent GETs:

```
(defun login (username password)
  "Logs in to www.example.com.  Returns a cookie-jar containing authentication details."
  (let ((cookie-jar (make-instance 'drakma:cookie-jar)))
    (drakma:http-request "http://www.example.com/login"
             :method :post
             :parameters `(("username" . ,username) ("password" . ,password))
             :cookie-jar cookie-jar)
    cookie-jar))

; snip

(defun get-page (page-num cookie-jar)
  "Downloads a potentially invalid HTML page containing data to scrape.  Returns a string containing the HTML."
  (let ((url (concatenate 'string "http://www.example.com/data/" (write-to-string page-num))))
    (let ((body (drakma:http-request url :cookie-jar cookie-jar)))
      (if (search "No data found." body)
    nil
  body))))
```

However, I can't find an equivalent in Racket.  The [latest HTTP library](https://github.com/plt/racket/blob/master/racket/collects/net/http-client.rkt) makes no mention of cookies at all, and AFAICT the [cookie library](http://docs.racket-lang.org/net/cookie.html) seems more about correctly serializing and deserializing them.

Can anyone suggest a way of re-writing the above CL in Racket without having to implement a bunch of header-parsing stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such functionality in the Racket libraries (at the time of writing, 30 Jan 2014).

There has been [some discussion](http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2014-January/060984.html) on the Racket users list about this, and there is a third-party library called [client-cookies](https://github.com/Kalimehtar/client-cookies) that addresses the issue.  At the time of writing that library is not yet production-ready, but is under active development.